# How to use mongoose.Schema.pre() in typescript environment?

Tags: mongoose

```js
userSchema.pre('save',(next)=>{
    if(!this.isModified('password')){
        return next();
    }
    this.password = user.encryptPassword(this.password);
    next();
})
```

In the above code, typescript compiler tell me that 'this' is type of 'globalThis'. However, in JavaScript, we always consider it has the type of 'mongoose.Document'. Here I want to access the method "isModified" of the certain mongoose.Document object and we can only use 'this' to access it. 
How to make the typescript compiler know or consider the 'this' has the type of mongoose.Document ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you use of **arrow functions**. The arrow function will bring the actual context to the underlying function. The soluce is to remove the use of arrow function so the natural context of the function will apply. like :

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if(!this.isModified('password')){
        return next();
    }

    this.password = user.encryptPassword(this.password);

    next();
});
```